# How to write a Cosmos DB query to get child array without the child array name

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it possible to write a query to get the child array without it's name?

I know two methods to get a child array, but both of the, return the JSON file with the child array name included. Is there any way to not get that child array name

Expected output:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "acvb",
            "addr": "bca",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "zxc",
            "addr": "evd",
            "age": 22
        }

]
```

Actual output:

```
[
    {
        "event": [
            {
                "name": "acvb",
                "addr": "bca",
                "age": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "zxc",
                "addr": "evd",
                "age": 22
            } 
         ]  
      },
   {}
 ]
```

Query that I am using

```
SELECT c.event FROM c
```

Also I noticed that I am getting back an empty object {} after the array of objects. I running it on Cosmos DB and got this result, it seems I get this no matter how I give the query. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input data looks like:

```
{
    "id": "something",
    "_partitionKey": "partition key value",
    "event": [
        {
            "name": "acvb",
            "addr": "bca",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "zxc",
            "addr": "evd",
            "age": 22
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM c IN t.event
```

It will produce the following output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "acvb",
        "addr": "bca",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "zxc",
        "addr": "evd",
        "age": 22
    }
]
```

For more details, please see this blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/understanding-how-to-query-arrays-in-azure-cosmos-db/.